# Cannot connect to Pi 4 through hostname (SSH and VNC)

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS. I was able to ping it or connect through SSH and VNC through IP address. But I can't ping it, can't connect it with hostname.

I have tried using my Macbook to do so, and it works without a problem. I can ping and I can connect to my Raspberry Pi with hostname.

One weird thing I notice is that when my Windows is turned on, it can ping and connect with hostname. But then I won't be able to do so after maybe 5 minutes.

How can I use hostname to connect my Pi?

Comment: "can't connect it with hostname.…

it works without a problem" make up your mind.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about your network and router.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 3 possible ways that the hostname is translated to the IP address.

- hosts table
- DNS
- mDNS

The hosts-table on Windows is at `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. If you put the hostname and IP address of your Pi therein, it will work.

DNS assumes that you have a DNS server somewhere in you network. Your Pi needs to be in the configuration files for the DNS server. As we do not know anything about your network-setup, it is hard to give recomendations here.

mDNS is multicast DNS. It is a form of DNS that works only on a local subnet.  If your PC and Pi are on the same subnet, you can access the Pi through its hostname (in general: `raspberrypi.local`). The `.local` domain is more or less reserved for mDNS.

If your macbook can connect without trouble, I would assume that the configuration of the Pi is correct, and that name resolution works (either DNS or mDNS). I would therefore shift my attention to the Windows installation.